# Script to add iPad as a linked keyboard/mouse?

Tags: macos, monterey, universal-control

I have 2 macbook pros in clamshell that I swap between using a KVM switch. I have to manually re-add my iPad as a linked keyboard/mouse every time I swap macs. Note that I can't enable "**Push through the edge of a display...**" or "**Automatically reconnect to any nearby Mac or iPad**" because then it will connect both my iPad *and* other macbook (but I only want the iPad to connect).

Is there a way to either:

1. Make a script to add my iPad as a linked keyboard/mouse as shown below
2. Connect my iPad as a linked keyboard/mouse through a physical connection while keeping it charged through a KVM switch?

[image]

Here is my KVM switch: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B095DDPKN3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B095DDPKN3)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a combination of [display-switch](https://github.com/haimgel/display-switch) and [blueutil](https://github.com/toy/blueutil) to solve my problem.

I use `display-switch` to listen for my KVM switch USB connection/disconnection, then utilize their `on_usb_connect_execute`/`on_usb_disconnect_execute` commands to call `blueutil` to turn off bluetooth on disconnect (so the macbook I'm switching away from won't auto connect to the next macbook I'm switching to). And also make sure to turn bluetooth back ON on USB connection.

This way I'm able to turn on Universal Control's **Automatically reconnect to any nearby Mac or iPad** setting.

It does still take about a minute for the iPad connection to establish automatically, but it seems to work reliably.

Note that for now I had to [fork display-switch](https://github.com/rajohns08/display-switch) until/if my PR fix for macOS 12.4 gets merged in.